# How is DECIMAL(m, n) represented in a 64-bit system?

Tags: mysql

What is the relationship between a `DECIMAL(m,n)` column specification and the actual representation of that column in a 64-bit MySQL implementation?

I'm defining tables in a context where I know I need an exact value (hence `DECIMAL`) and I don't know how sensitive I am to truncation errors in the decimal portion. I'd therefore like to choose a column specification that makes reasonable use of the underlying storage (I know it's a 64-bit system).

I haven't yet found an answer in the MySQL documentation despite a reasonable search.

Comment: The internal binary representation within the database is irrelevant. It is fixed point, hence precise. If the precision is stored separately, it might be int/long. In the early years there was also BCD, unsuited though. More important is the programming language: Java should use BigDecimal. Languages which might reside to floating point might fall back to strings.

Comment: It surely affects the size of the resulting database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't matter if you're using a 64-bit MySQL build. DECIMAL supports precision greater than 64 bits.

DECIMAL uses 4 bytes for each 9 digits, plus extra bytes for the leftover digits. For example, DECIMAL(32,0) supports up to 9+9+9+5 digits. It will use 4+4+4 bytes for the first 27 digits, then 3 more bytes for the remaining 5 digits. A total of 12+3, or 15 bytes.

The fractional part of the decimal value (after the decimal point) stores digits similarly. So DECIMAL(32,9) would support up to 9+9+5 digits for the integer portion and another 9 digits for the fractional portion. Thus 4+4+3 bytes for the integer and 4 bytes for the fractional part.

There's a more detailed description with examples down to the byte, in the code comments for the `decimal2bin()` function here:
https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/8.0/strings/decimal.cc#L1282-L1343

Comment: Indeed, I found the same description myself after writing the question.

So if I define the field as "DECIMAL(12, 8)", I think it will require 10 bytes of storage. Is that consistent with your understanding?

Comment: Yes, it's also described in the MySQL online doc about numeric data type storage requirements: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/storage-requirements.html#data-types-storage-reqs-numeric

Comment: Thanks, I've marked this as the correct answer.

I appreciate your response!

Comment: The precision of the DECIMAL type is the total number of digits, and the scale is the subset of those digits for the fractional portion. So DECIMAL(12,8) is 4 digits of integer plus 8 digits of fractional part. Based on the formula they give, that would be 2 bytes for the integer portion, with 4 bytes for the fractional portion.

Comment: Hmm. In `DECIMAL(12, 8)`, the value of `m` is 12. That's one 9 and 3 leftover, or 4 + 2 = 6 bytes for m. The value of `n` is 8, which is zero 9s and 8 leftover = 0 + 4 = 4 bytes for `n`. So my read of the table is 10 bytes total, 6 for `m` and 4 for `n`. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: DECIMAL(12, 8) defines a column with 12 digits _total_ precision, 8 digits of which are after the decimal point. So only four digits for the integer part before the decimal point.

Comment: The documentation is extraordinarily misleading. I understand how the specification works. In the MySQL documentation, surely it would help to clarify that the "integer" part of `DECIMAL(m,n)` is `m-n`.

I appreciate your patience in explaining this.

Comment: In their defense, you're not supposed to have to know how the data is stored. That's the point of an abstraction layer like SQL. It's still not clear why you want to know this.

Comment: I'm designing schema for a database that is expected to contain tens of millions of rows. Many of those rows have multiple fields with `DECIMAL` values like this. The system will run on an AWS EC2 instance. I need to know how much storage to allocate for the EBS volume where the database will be stored. Sooner or later SOMEBODY has to know how the data is stored in order to assure that there is enough disk space available to hold that data.